# haskell iterate in list comprehensions

Tags: haskell

i want to do this in Haskell

for `MyString = "ab"` and `n = 4` the result should be >

```
["aaaa","aaab","aaba","aabb","abaa","abab","abba","abbb","baaa","baab","baba","babb","bbaa","bbab","bbba","bbbb"]
```

Comment: We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
replicateM 4 "ab"
```

gives what you ask for. You can import it from `Control.Monad`.

Comment: Worth noting that this is using the list monad, so this is the special case `Int -> [a] -> [[a]]` of the more general type `Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write it your self you could do the following.

```
seq i xs | i > 0 = [x:ys | x <- xs, ys <- seq (i-1) xs]
         | otherwise = [[]]
```